# Make a spreadsheet public with the Google Sheets API?

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I would like to programmatically create a Google Sheet using the Google Sheets API, make it public, and embed it into an IFRAME on a webpage.

I can't figure out how to make the spreadsheet visible to the public using the API. Is there a setting for this in the API when you create or update the spreadsheet?

I followed [Google's Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python) and was able to create and update spreadsheets.

#### Update:

Using the Drive API I can make the spreadsheet public, and I can access it from other accounts. However, this does not allow you to embed it in a webpage (It still states "We're sorry. This document is not published." in the frame). There must be another setting for this. **Is it possible to set this with the Drive API?**

FWIW here is what I was able to do to make it public (but still unable to embedd the sheet in an iframe)

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

drive_client = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
user_permission = {
    'type': 'anyone',
    'role': 'reader',
}
result =drive_client.permissions().create(
    fileId=sheed_id,
    body=user_permission,
).execute()
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this via an API? Just open your Google Drive, get the sharable link that'll never change, then copy it wherever

Comment: @cricket_007 There are plenty of good reasons; maybe they need to publish 1000 of them, or a new one every day, or...

Comment: @Thomas Ah, didn't think about scalability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Permissions are part of Google Drive and not specific to Spreadsheets, so you need to use the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-sharing) for that. See the [reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/permissions).

Comment: Thanks, I was able to make it public, but I was not able to embedd it in a webpage. Is there perhaps another setting for this, which could be set by the API?

Answer (score 0):

For those ending up at this question while searching for a solution to the publishing of embedded content issue:

publishing files using the google drive api is possible through revisions.

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
          'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

drive_client = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

drive_client.revisions().update(
    fileId=spreadSheetId,
    revisionId=1,
    body={
        "published": True,
        "publishAuto": True,
        "publishedOutsideDomain": True
    }
).execute()
```

Depending if you want to make these available only inside or also outside of your domain, you can set these settings accordingly.

ref: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/revisions